# How to cleanup (free memory) when using multiprocessing.Array() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, ctypes, free

I'm using [`multiprocessing.Array()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) to create shared memory with a my parent and child process (kicked-off with [`multiprocessing.Process()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process)). I'd like to `free()` the memory that was allocated to the [ctypes array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char) by `Array()`. How can I do that?

Consider the following example python script that defines a simple `helloWorld()` function that takes a byte array in shared memroy and stores "hello world!" to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import multiprocessing

# this function will be executed in a child process asynchronously
def helloWorld( shm_string ):
    shm_string.value =  bytes( 'hello world!', 'utf-8' )

# alloc()
shm_string = multiprocessing.Array( 'c', 256 )

# execute the helloWorld() function in a child process in the background
process = multiprocessing.Process(
 target = helloWorld,
 args = (shm_string,),
)
process.start()

# <this is where async stuff would happen>

# wait for the process to finish
# and free() the resources allocated for the Process()
process.join()

# get the string out of shared memory
result = shm_string.value.decode( 'utf-8' )
print(result)

# free()
#free(shm_string)??
```

As you can see above, the function `helloWorld()` is executed in a child process using `multiprocessing.Process()`, and it's passed our byte array in shared memory.

Here is an example execution:

```
user@host:~$ python3 example3.py 
hello world!
user@host:~$
```

How can I update the above script to actually `free()` the memory that was allocated for the byte array (referenced by `shm_string`) after we no longer need it?

Comment: Isn't the garbage collector taking care of freeing that resource once is no longer used?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the garbage collector to free resources that are still assigned to a variable! I thought that maybe setting `shm_string = None` would remove all references to the memory and trigger the GC to deallocate the memory. If this is true, then please post it as a solution. But be sure to actually prove it by showing the memory is allocated before the `shm_string = None`, wait for some time, and then prove that the memory is no longer allocated. In my non-simplified case, `shm_string` is actually a long-living instance field of an object.